# Finding an item in array knockout

Tags: html, knockout.js

I am trying to assign a variable to an item in an array that has a specific value for a property. For example, I am trying to grab the item that has "Id" value = 15. The way I am currently doing it, I am only returning the first item in the array, no matter the Id value I am inserting.

```
var credential = ko.utils.arrayFirst(allCredentialsList, function (credential) {
        return credential.Id = id;
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the `===` (or `==`) comparison operator, not the `=` assignment operator.

```
var credential = ko.utils.arrayFirst(allCredentialsList, function (credential) {
    return credential.Id === id;
});
```